# Which MIME to use if I want to include text version of email and attach files

Tags: html, email, smtp, mime-types, content-type

As I understand email can contain only one main `Content-Type` header, is it correct?  Whether you want to send message with files attached to it, or message with html content along with plain text version you should use **Multipart Content-Type**. And within each part one can also explicitly specify content-type for that particular part.

From [rfc1341](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html) I gathered that that there are two main subtypes of multipart content-type:

- The Multipart/mixed (primary) subtype
- The Multipart/alternative subtype

If I would want to include both html and plain text versions I would use **Multipart/alternative** as upper outermost `Content-Type` header since its semantical meaning, which is (from [rfc1341](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html)):

> In particular, each of the parts is an "alternative" version of the same information. User agents should recognize that the content of the various parts are interchangeable. The user agent should either choose the "best" type based on the user's environment and preferences, or offer the user the available alternatives. In general, choosing the best type means displaying only the LAST part that can be displayed. This may be used, for example, to send mail in a fancy text format in such a way that it can easily be displayed anywhere

On the other hand, if I need to attach files I should use **The Multipart/mixed**
 as stated  in [rfc1341](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html):

> Mixed is intended for use when the body parts are independent and intended to be displayed serially

which is obviously the case when you want to attach files.

But how do I send email with files **AND** with text version i.e. when I want some parts of my multipart letter to show serially (main content and attachments), while other parts to show interchangeably (html and plain text)? What outermost `Content-Type` header should I use then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You encapsulate a multipart/alternative within a multipart/mixed.

In other words, if you wanted a text and HTML body and also attach a zip file, the MIME tree structure would look like this:

```
multipart/mixed
  multipart/alternative
    text/plain
    text/html
  application/zip
```

Comment: That seems right. Any chance you have an example of such mail?